# Get null values in Ruby Spreadsheet gem

Tags: ruby, excel, spreadsheet

I'm trying to take an excel file and put it into Postgres. I can access the file and read rows from it.

```
require 'spreadsheet'
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
book = Spreadsheet.open 'C:\test\RubyTestFile.xls'
sheet1 = book.worksheet 0
$test_array = []
sheet1.each do |row|
    $test_array += row
end
print $test_array
```

My problem is that it won't read null values. Is there a method to grab say 3 columns of every row? Should I handle this when I upload to postgres instead? Is there a better way of doing this? I tried searching but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Remember that `$test_array` is a global variable here and there's really no need for that. Also try `test_array << row` which adds to the existing array rather than `+=` which creates a copy.

Comment: If I don't make it a global variable then I can't use it inside of my method. I'm new to Ruby and don't understand scope quite yet.

Comment: There's no method shown here, but if there was, just return that from your method. Jamming things into global variables gets unmaintainable extremely quickly. Are you asking "how do I ensure each row has 3 elements, regardless of how many are extracted from the spreadsheet"?

Comment: << doesn't work. I get a huge output that basically includes every bit of information of every cell.

Comment: What output do you want instead? That's what this code appears to be intending to do.

Comment: Yes. I want a fixed amount of columns per row. I want it to read. 'value' 'value' 'null' ' value'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly more Ruby interpretation:

```
require 'spreadsheet'

Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'

def read_spreadsheet(path)
  book = Spreadsheet.open(path)
  sheet1 = book.worksheet 0

  test_array = [ ]

  sheet1.each do |row|
    test_array << (row + [ nil ] * 3).first(3)
  end

  test_array
end

puts read_spreadsheet('C:\test\RubyTestFile.xls').inspect
```

If you'd rather have literal `'null'` in there, you can substitute that for the `nil` in the array there.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks!. Just a few questions. Could you explain (row+ [nil] * 3).first(3)? I understand first(3) would be the 3 columns. But I don't understand (row + [nil] * 3). To me this seems like you are adding [nil] * 3 to row.  also the last line in the method is test_array. does this act like a return?

Comment: It's just a way to ensure that you have at least 3 elements in the array regardless of what state it starts in. `first(3)` then trims it to the first 3 elements. `[nil] * 3` ends up being `[nil, nil, nil]` when expanded. As for the last line, in Ruby that's the default way of passing something along, it's the *implicit* `return`. The result of the last statement in a method is what the method returns unless you explicitly `return` something else.

Comment: But how does Ruby know what is going to stay a nil value and what isn't? It seems to me that if row was ['val',nil, 'val'] and you added [nil,nil,nil] the result would be ['val', 'val',nil,nil,nil]. first(3) would cut it down to ['val', 'val', nil] Maybe I'm over-thinking it. Ruby seems to know what the user wants and I'm not use to that.

Comment: `first(3)` takes the first three elements, not dropping any `nil` values. If you want to drop those, you must call `compact`, it won't exclude them unless you go out of your way to do it. Try it in `irb` if you don't believe me: `['v', nil, 'v'] + ['x']` becomes `['v', nil, 'v', 'x']`

Comment: I think I worded my reply poorly. What I mean is how are you getting null cells to display in the array as nil when before they were just being skipped over?

Comment: I think the "skipping" is an artifact of the Spreadsheet library which simply trims them off for you as a convenience method. Otherwise you'd get large numbers of empty cells in a typical spreadsheet.